# Why is Android Studio Emulator process being killed on every run?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am currently trying to run my application I have created using Android Studio 4.1

When running the AVD emulator within Android Studio (new to v4.1) and every time it fails to run the emulator I am given this error `Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD Pixel_2_API_30 was killed.` The device will get to this point then give me the error I have stated above (https://prnt.sc/v23wce)

I have tried creating new virtual devices to see if the one I was currently using was the issue but I am getting the same issue no matter the virtual device I am using.  I have also tried wiping the data on the device but that has not seemed to fix the issue as well.

The details of the device I am using is below

```
Name: Pixel_2_API_30

CPU/ABI: Google Play Intel Atom (x86)

Path: C:\Users\Mason\.android\avd\Pixel_2_API_30.avd

Target: google_apis_playstore [Google Play] (API level 30)

Skin: pixel_2

SD Card: 512M

fastboot.chosenSnapshotFile: 

runtime.network.speed: full

hw.accelerometer: yes

hw.device.name: pixel_2

hw.lcd.width: 1080

hw.initialOrientation: Portrait

image.androidVersion.api: 30

tag.id: google_apis_playstore

hw.mainKeys: no

hw.camera.front: emulated

avd.ini.displayname: Pixel 2 API 30

hw.gpu.mode: auto

hw.ramSize: 1536

PlayStore.enabled: true

fastboot.forceColdBoot: no

hw.cpu.ncore: 4

hw.keyboard: yes

hw.sensors.proximity: yes

hw.dPad: no

hw.lcd.height: 1920

vm.heapSize: 256

skin.dynamic: yes

hw.device.manufacturer: Google

hw.gps: yes

hw.audioInput: yes

image.sysdir.1: system-images\android-30\google_apis_playstore\x86\

showDeviceFrame: yes

hw.camera.back: virtualscene

AvdId: Pixel_2_API_30

hw.lcd.density: 420

hw.arc: false

hw.device.hash2: MD5:55acbc835978f326788ed66a5cd4c9a7

fastboot.forceChosenSnapshotBoot: no

fastboot.forceFastBoot: yes

hw.trackBall: no

hw.battery: yes

hw.sdCard: yes

tag.display: Google Play

runtime.network.latency: none

disk.dataPartition.size: 6442450944

hw.sensors.orientation: yes

avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8

hw.gpu.enabled: yes
```

I am unsure as to why I am receiving this error and any help would be appreciated.